# How to correctly throw an error from child process

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

I have an express controller, and my idea was to execute child process, and if there was an error , throw it and catch on a client. If I do it like below, when I throw error it crash whole running process, I can't handle an error and I have to restart my server.

```
const { fork } = require('child_process')

const foo = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const _process = fork(path.join(__dirname, '../myfile.js'))

  _process.send({ data: req.body })
  _process.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.error) {
      res.status(500)
      throw new Error(message.error)
    } eles res.status(200).send()
  })
})
```

If I throw an error like this, it ok, I can handle it on client, nothing crashes but this time it throws an error before child process ends.

```
const { fork } = require('child_process')

const foo = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const _process = fork(path.join(__dirname, '../myfile.js'))
  let _message = null
   _message.error = 'THIS MESSAGE WILL BE THROWN'
  
  _process.send({ data: req.body })
  _process.on('message', (message) => {
    _message = message
  })

  if (_message.error) {
    res.status(500)
    throw new Error(message.error)
  } else res.status(200).send()
})
```

So, does anyone know how to throw an error correctly after child process ends?